# Why is it necessary to have Daylight information in iCal files

Tags: timezone, icalendar, dst, ical4j

I want to understand why is it mandatory to give daylight information in ical files generated by us . Why does not GMT/ UTC times just suffice and why email client like MS Outlook 2010 will not handle it.

Comment: Read link : http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/vtimezone.html

Comment: Found answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669096/should-event-times-specified-in-utc-while-generating-ics-files-to-avoid-issues. Appologies for not searching well.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason is that there may or may not be a time zone on the computer that matches the `TZID` specified.  iCAL allows time zone IDs of any type, including IANA time zones like `"America/Bogota"` and Windows time zones like `"SA Pacific Standard Time"`.

The time zone information on the system specified by the TZID should be preferred when it is available, but it might not be available.  One might be looking at an iCal file generated on a Windows machine while running on a Mac.  Or one might not have all the current time zone updates and the TZID might refer to a newly created time zone that hasn't yet been installed on the machine.

Encoding the rules into the iCAL file is essential to support interoperability.  It does come with the downside of those rules being fixed to their known values from when the event was created.  If the rules change before the event takes place, the event could occur at the wrong time - depending on how the file was interpreted.  That's why it's a better idea to use the information on the system when you have a match by TZID.

Regarding why UTC does not suffice for scheduling, that's because events are almost always specified in terms of a *local* time.  That local time's relation to UTC is highly dependent on the time zone, which is set by the particular local government.  These have to account for daylight saving time and other anomalies, and governments can change their minds.

As an example, if a recurring appointment was scheduled for 8:00 AM local time every day in the US Pacific time zone, during standard time that would occur at 4:00 PM UTC, and during daylight time it would occur at 5:00 PM UTC.   If instead I scheduled by UTC, then my local time would be an hour off before or after a DST transition.  This is commonly refereed to as the "alarm clock problem", and was the culprit of [the 2010 iPhone DST bug](http://appleinsider.com/articles/10/11/01/european_alarms_go_off_an_hour_late_due_to_apple_iphone_clock_bug), among others.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the original purpose of the iCalendar specification was to provide an independent file format that would be interpreted identically by all calendar user agents (CUAs), such as Outlook. As you can't assume that all CUAs share the same timezone information it must be included in the file format.

In reality however, it is often more practical to use the built-in timezone definitions, in which case you can just specify all time values in UTC (ie. With the appended "Z")

Comment: The current implementation we have is : BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0000
TZOFFSETTO:-0000
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE ,     DTEND;TZID=GMT:20151007T011500
DTSTAMP:20151009T232113Z
DTSTART;TZID=GMT:20151007T001500 this causes one hour off in outlook when there is a cross over in DST . Some pages in stackoverflow say i need to give timezone with DST info. is that mandatory

Comment: All in UTC without timezone gives one hour off . Works if i give timezone info with daylight timings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669096/should-event-times-specified-in-utc-while-generating-ics-files-to-avoid-issues